# Firebase cloud function: PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-security

I have successfully deployed this cloud function:

```js
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";

admin.initializeApp();

export const setTimestampsOnCreate = functions.firestore
  .document("listings/{listingId}")
  .onCreate((snapshot) => {
    const currentTime = admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp();
    return snapshot.ref.set(
      {
        createdAt: currentTime,
        updatedAt: currentTime,
      },
      {
        merge: true,
      }
    );
  });
```

However, when creating new listings documents, `createdAt` and `updatedAt` are not being added. I checked the logs in the Logs explorer and found this error:

```json
{
  "textPayload": "Error: 7 PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions.\n    at callErrorFromStatus (/workspace/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call.js:31:19)\n    at Object.onReceiveStatus (/workspace/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client.js:192:76)\n    at Object.onReceiveStatus (/workspace/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client-interceptors.js:360:141)\n    at Object.onReceiveStatus (/workspace/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client-interceptors.js:323:181)\n    at /workspace/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/resolving-call.js:94:78\n    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:77:11)",
  "insertId": "648c810100046b55a3b3ea4f",
  "resource": {
    "type": "cloud_function",
    "labels": {
      "function_name": "setTimestampsOnCreate",
      "region": "us-central1",
      "project_id": "dormati-b29a7"
    }
  },
  "timestamp": "2023-06-16T15:34:25.289621Z",
  "severity": "ERROR",
  "labels": {
    "execution_id": "vari4x48stwl",
    "instance_id": "00c61b117c1342606ee33c4d28125c6d7ba2dcd7215ff5c73a638d22ae9493e04c4084cd5d939a0b57611457dd7a995861e27d42855de30f7409"
  },
  "logName": "projects/dormati-b29a7/logs/cloudfunctions.googleapis.com%2Fcloud-functions",
  "trace": "projects/dormati-b29a7/traces/81c8252d3f8a88d38473231c8c65d86d",
  "receiveTimestamp": "2023-06-16T15:34:25.612947313Z"
}
```

There are no Firestore rules in place, and the Blaze pricing plan is enabled for creating cloud functions. What could be causing this error, and how can I resolve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The service account used by the Cloud Function
is probably missing the Firebase Realtime Database Admin role.

Link: https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/iam/roles-predefined-product#realtime-database